# unable to create/overwrte file in shell script?

Tags: shell, applescript

I tried with the below script to create the  congif file, if its alredy present to overwrite the same,
but am not getting any result even though am not getting any errors, pls suggest.
I want the same in applescript as below.

```
property usr : "abce"
property pswd : "pwd"
do shell script "echo 'hello world' > /users/usernamr/desktop/mms.cfg" user name usr password pswd with administrator privileges
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
property usr : "abce"
property pswd : "pwd"

set filePath to (path to desktop as text) & "mms.cfg"
set theText to "hello world"
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of theText & " > " & quoted form of POSIX path of filePath user name usr password pswd with administrator privileges
```

NOTE: I see in your other post that the file is in your application support folder. If you want the file there then use this line...

```
set filePath to (path to application support folder from user domain as text) & "mms.cfg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a misspelling:

```
/users/usernamr/desktop/mms.cfg
```

Try changing it to:

```
/users/username/desktop/mms.cfg
```

?